# How to make buckets from a big Json file in Python?

Tags: python, json, mongodb, bucket, ijson

I have the following local Json file (around 90MB):

[image]

For my data to be accessible, I want to create smaller JSON files that include exactly the same data but only 100 of the array entries in `Readings.SensorData` every time. So a file that includes the first 100 readings, then a file that includes readings 101-200, and so on... I am aware about the [ijson](https://pypi.org/project/ijson/) library but I cannot figure out to do this in the most memory effective way.

Edit: Just to note I know how to do this with the standard JSON library but because it is a big file I want to be able to do this in a way that doesn't come to a complete halt.

Answer (score 0):

Use
dict.items() in python

You will need 
json, package in python

Use json.loads() features and it will result in a python dictionary.

Comment: Thanks I'm looking to avoid using the standard library as this is a large amount of data and loading it all would cause the system to be slow.